# Sunspot only can search one column in table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot, rails-postgresql, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I can search the customer by name.

But can not search any data with phone and email.

Is there something wrong?

controller

```
@customer = Customer.search do |q|
  ap(params[:customer_query])
  q.keywords params[:customer_query]
end
```

model

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base


  searchable do
    text  :phone    
    text  :name
    text  :email
  end

end
```

datatable

```
+-----+----------+------------+------------+-
| id  | name     | email      | phone      | 
+-----+----------+------------+------------+-
| 1   | 林x為   | trinity... | 033151006 |  
| 2   | 林x仁   | percy.r... | 088277137 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
@customer = Customer.search do
  ap(params[:customer_query])
  keywords params[:customer_query]
end.results
```

Answer (score 1):

First, for your model, you can have multiple fields lined up if they are the same type. Also, if your phone field isn't a string, you'll need to index it as an integer. You might want to try something like this:

```
searchable do    
  text  :name, :email
  integer  :phone
end
```

For your controller, you might want to try something like this:

```
@search = Customer.search do 
  fulltext params[:customer_query]
end

@customer = @search.results
```